# Can you dual boot without a boot manager

Tags: linux, boot, android, boot-manager, dualboot

I have a TV box. I want to dual boot Linux and Android, however this device doesn't have a boot manager, how do I do it?

Comment: What device? Do you realize that boot managers are software?

Comment: You can [contact support](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged. This way you'll be able to edit without being queued for review and accept answers.

Comment: _Something_ has to allow you to make the choice on what to boot.

Answer (score 1):

You're carefully avoiding revealing any details that would give us any idea what we're dealing with, but it's probably some kind of embedded ARM device.

These are not like PCs where you have plenty of choices, you can freely install any kind of OS and it will work perfectly fine or at least be usable, and the worst case scenario is you'll have to reinstall from scratch. It's quite the opposite.

Devices like this are proprietary and not designed to be tampered. If it's not designed to have software modified by end user (and it's not), someone will have to find a bug that will allow for installation of 3rd party firmware. It's some custom ARM-based hardware not adhering to any particular standard, so installing generic Linux distributions is not an option. Someone has to scout the original firmware, see what's available and build an OS designed for this particular device. There's no standardized hardware interface that will work with generic drivers, you need stuff for this particular configuration. Repartitioning to fit in second OS is highly discouraged and probably won't work with stock firmware. Mistakes will make the device unbootable and unless you can put its bootloader into flashing mode, it will become an expensive paperweight.

In other words: if you have to ask this question, you shouldn't try to dual-boot this device, and if such solution wasn't built and documented by the community yet, you won't be able to do it yourself with your current knowledge. Even if it was already invented, there's some inherent risk to this process and you probably shouldn't try to do that without a lot of reading about it first.